# Can't connect to Oracle database

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, oracle

I am working on an ASP.NET project, which uses C# for code-behind.  It attempts to connect to an Oracle database using the following code, which already existed in the project when I began working on it:

```
OracleConnection myConnection = new OracleConnection();
myConnection.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["OraFinCnString"].ConnectionString;
myConnection.Open();
```

The application runs locally (opens up in a browser on `localhost`), and attempts to connect to a remote Oracle Database.  When I run it, the The last line above gives the following error:

"InvalidOperationException was unhandled by user code.  Attempt to load Oracle client libraries threw BadImageFormatException.  This problem will occur when running in 64 bit mode with the 32 bit Oracle client components installed."

The connection string was provided by my client, so I presume it is correct, and this doesn't seem like the sort of error that would be caused by incorrect connection information.  But I'm pretty well stumped as to exactly what the problem is, and would appreciate any insight.

Comment: Does the machine this is running on have the Oracle client software installed?

Comment: OracleConnection, you are using Oracle.DataAccess.Client  or the System.Data.OracleClient, if you are using the first one, i think it is a problem with your dll version, try to get teh correct one, I think you are running on a windows 64 bits, if not try to use the System.Data.OracleClient

Comment: Is the OracleConnection a third party assembly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please take a look at the following link. You will need to Install Oracle 11g Oracle Data Access Components

[Oracle Provider](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/dotnet/GettingStartedNETVersion/GettingStartedNETVersion.htm)

Comment: That would be my guess as well.